# Invariant Violation: View config not found for name div. Make sure to start component names with a capital letter

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to React Native. This is my error:

[image: this is the error i am getting]

My code looks like this:

**Toolbar.js**
import React from 'react';

```
const Toolbar = props => (
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div></div>
            <div><a href="/">THE LOGO</a></div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Users</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
);

export default Toolbar;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Toolbar from './components/Toolbar/Toolbar' 

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Toolbar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

Comment: Please add code what you have tried so could help you whats doing wrong.

Comment: @raju_eww just edited the question i think you can see the code now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the components in your Toolbar not having capital letters. On further investigation you can see that you are trying to use html tags. You can’t use html tags in React-Native. Tags like `<div>`, `<header>`, `<nav>` etc.  have no value in React-Native.

You need to use React-Native components like `<View>` or `<Text>` to construct your views.